# Contents Magration from SharePoint Server 2007 to SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

Can i migrate specific content from site like "content of Document Library" from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to move the content of one specific document library, you could choose the option "Open with Explorer" in your document libraries and just copy the items.

Datasheet view seems to be a viable solution to transfer meta informations, if you're not trying to copy too many elements.

A tool like [Avepoints Migrator for SharePoint](http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/) seems a little bit over the top.

Comment: Thx for your reply, i conclude that the only way to move the content of multiple specific document library is by using a certain tool..

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools available for migration from Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2013. Just google "Sharepoint migration tools". Here is an article that provides some details: http://www.threewill.com/2013/03/the-final-four-or-five-sharepoint-migration-tools/

Comment: can i found free tool, i have contents size greater then 100GB.
Regards